# How to add multiple CSS styles to an element with .css()

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm aware on how to add styles to nested elements using jQuery and JavaScript but for some reason I can't figure out how to add a style to a *deeply nested* element.

I'm using WordPress for my site and it has added a bunch of divs around the element that I am trying to reach.

I am trying to style the element with the class name `.bx-wrapper`. However, I only want to style the `.bx-wrapper` that is nested inside of the class `.associate-wrapper`.

Here is my current HTML:

```
<div class="row associate-wrapper">
  <li id="black-studio-tinymce-16" class="widget">
    <div class="textwidget">
      <div class="row"></div>
      <div class="col-md-12 text-center"></div>
      <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <div class="bx-wrapper">
          <p>content....</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</div>
```

And here is my current *non-working* jQuery:

```
$('.associate-wrapper').find('.bx-wrapper').css('position', 'absolute', 'margin-top', '30px');
```

Comment: Your selector looks right... is it possible that the content you are selecting doesn't exist in the DOM when you are trying to access it?

Comment: Your selector is correct. The problem is likely that your CSS styles are not working as you expect them to work. See http://jsfiddle.net/55tvdbbL/

Comment: I'm glad to know I was at least doing the selector right. I'll take a deeper look to see if maybe they don't exist in the DOM at that time. I know the CSS that I am using works because I've used Inspect Element on that div to experiment with the styling before I actually implement it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you are adding more than one property to your jQuery `.css()` tag, you will need to make slight adjustments to your `.css()` syntax like this:

```
$('.associate-wrapper').find('.bx-wrapper').css({'position': 'absolute', 'margin-top': '30px'});
```

[JSFiddle with above script](http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/65sf2f66/28/)

---

Or you can just change the selectors the same way CSS does **and** as mentioned above, since you are adding more than one property to your jQuery `.css()` tag, you will have to write your script like this:

```
$('.associate-wrapper .bx-wrapper').css({"position": "absolute", "margin-top": "30px"});
```

[JSFiddle with above script](http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/65sf2f66/29/)